# Convert Indexed Array To Multi Dimensional array in php

Tags: php, arrays

Hi I Have An Indexed Array Like This I Have Been Trying To Figure Out How can i change it to multi dimensional after every 4 elements:

```
array(8) {
  [0]=>
  string(3) "yes"
  [1]=>
  string(11) "John DOE"
  [2]=>
  string(3) "116"
  [3]=>
  string(15) "John DOE.jpeg"
  [4]=>
  string(24) "No"
  [5]=>
  string(11) "John Snow"
  [6]=>
  string(3) "116"
  [7]=>
  string(15) "JohnSnow.jpeg"
}
```

And I Want to have Something Like This a multidimensional array If Possible

```
array([0]=>{
    [0]=>'Yes',
    [1]=>'John Doe',
    [2]=>'116,
    [3]=>'JohnDoe.jpeg'
},[1]=>{
    [0]=>'No',
    [1]=>'John Snow',
    [2]=>'116,
    [3]=>'JohnSnow.jpeg'
}
```

Comment: Did you try [array_chunk](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php)?

Comment: yes it didn't worked

Comment: It work correctly https://3v4l.org/t2mbm

Comment: Try `print_r(array_chunk($array, 4));`

Comment: Ah! My Mistake Was using array Chunk Inside The For Loop Thanks

Answer (score -1):

you could also use this if you prefer to use core coding:-

```
<?php
$arr=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17];
$i=0;
$arra1=[];
$j=0;
foreach ($arr as $value) {
    $arr1[$j][$i]=$value;
    $i++;
    if($i==4){
        $i=0;
        $j++;
    }
}
print_r($arr1);
```

Comment: Array Chunk Is much better why use a long code when something is already provided by php